# Increase write performance of nosql database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

Currently i am using a System with MongoDB as the nosql database. I am storing objects with varying sizes from <10 kb to many MB. To test the performance i tried to store 3.2 MB objects as fast as possible with nodejs.

The performance of the database was around 30 MB/s (10 queries/sec ) which seems rather low considering the underlying system has a 400MB/s file write performance.

Are there other options that i should consider ? (Redis could be a problem because i cant keep the whole database in memory )

```
insert query update delete getmore command dirty  used flushes vsize   res qrw arw net_in net_out conn                time
 7    14     *0     *0       0     2|0  0.5% 42.6%       0 2.42G 1.44G 0|0 1|0  23.7m   66.8k    6 Jul 29 13:42:59.189
 6    13     *0     *0       0     1|0  0.4% 43.3%       0 2.44G 1.46G 0|0 1|0  23.7m   66.7k    6 Jul 29 13:43:00.189
 4    12     *0     *0       0     2|0  0.4% 43.7%       0 2.46G 1.47G 0|0 1|0  13.5m   3.46m    6 Jul 29 13:43:01.189
 7    15     *0     *0       0     2|0  0.4% 44.5%       0 2.48G 1.50G 0|0 1|0  27.1m   67.4k    6 Jul 29 13:43:02.190
 6    11     *0     *0       0     1|0  0.3% 45.2%       0 2.51G 1.52G 0|0 1|1  23.6m   66.2k    6 Jul 29 13:43:03.192
 7    14     *0     *0       0     3|0  0.2% 45.9%       0 2.53G 1.55G 0|0 1|1  23.7m   66.9k    6 Jul 29 13:43:04.190
 7    16     *0     *0       0     2|0  0.5% 46.6%       0 2.55G 1.56G 0|0 1|0  23.7m   67.2k    6 Jul 29 13:43:05.190
 7    14     *0     *0       0     2|0  0.4% 47.3%       0 2.57G 1.59G 0|0 1|0  23.7m   66.8k    6 Jul 29 13:43:06.189
 6    13     *0     *0       0     2|0  0.3% 48.0%       0 2.60G 1.61G 0|0 1|0  22.5m   63.6k    6 Jul 29 13:43:07.243
 7    12     *0     *0       0     3|0  0.2% 48.7%       0 2.62G 1.64G 0|0 1|0  24.8m   69.8k    6 Jul 29 13:43:08.198
```

Comment: you  'd  better  show  result  of  the  mongostat

Comment: I added the mongostat output.

Comment: the . reuslt  of . qrw . & arw . is low . it may caused by  your . application  please 
 use more   thread to  opreate your data